# Insert cab file in msi from custom action

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I'd like to insert cab file in my msi package at installation time. Is this possible?
There is immediate custom action:

```
UINT __stdcall CreateDataCab(MSIHANDLE hInstall) {
    MSIHANDLE hRec = MsiCreateRecord(1);
    UINT status = MsiRecordSetStream(hRec, 1, T("C:\\work\\Data2.cab"));

    MSIHANDLE hDb = MsiGetActiveDatabase(hInstall);
    MSIHANDLE hView = 0;
    status = MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDb, _T("INSERT INTO `_Streams` (`Name`, `Data`) VALUES ('Data2.cab', ?)"), &hView);
    status = MsiViewExecute(hView, hRec);
    status = MsiViewClose(hView);
    status = MsiCloseHandle(hView);
    status = MsiCloseHandle(hRec);
    status = MsiCloseHandle(hDb);
}
```

It is executed at the very beginning of INSTALL action. Value of `status` variable is always `ERROR_SUCCESS`. So everything seems to be fine. However in msi log I can see error triggered:

```
Action start 14:29:27: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:049]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:049]: Doing action: SetSilentInstall
Action start 14:29:27: SetSilentInstall.
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:051]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SILENT property. Its value is '/s'.
Action ended 14:29:27: SetSilentInstall. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:052]: Doing action: CreateDataCab
Action start 14:29:27: CreateDataCab.
MSI (s) (4C:1C) [14:29:27:072]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\windows\Installer\MSI3EC2.tmp, Entrypoint: CreateDataCab
MSI (s) (4C:B4) [14:29:27:074]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (4C:B4) [14:29:27:079]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 32604 (0x7F5C).
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:147]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (4C:14) [14:29:27:151]: Hello, I'm your 64bit Impersonated custom action server.
MSI (s) (4C!50) [14:32:22:069]: Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035
```

`Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035` log record indicates MSI error `2263 Could not open stream [2].` occured in custom action. Hex value of `-2147287035` is `FFFFFFFF80030005` which is likely to be `STG_E_ACCESSDENIED HRESULT - Access Denied`.
My first guess for this error was that MSI service can't access source file when trying to fetch it into the record. I relaxed permissions of `C:\work\Data2.cab` but no luck.
Then I decided to use path for not existing file in `MsiRecordSetStream()` call.
With this change `MsiRecordSetStream()` call returned `161` error. As there is no branching in `CreateDataCab()` it get executed up to the end and all MSI functions after `MsiRecordSetStream()` succeeded.
msi log:

```
Action start 16:11:02: CreateDataCab.
MSI (s) (4C:D8) [16:11:02:596]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\windows\Installer\MSI4154.tmp, Entrypoint: JreCreateDataCab
MSI (s) (4C:54) [16:11:02:597]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (4C:54) [16:11:02:605]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 34668 (0x876C).
MSI (s) (4C:6C) [16:11:02:682]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (4C:6C) [16:11:02:684]: Hello, I'm your 64bit Impersonated custom action server.
MSI (s) (4C!74) [16:11:18:565]: Note: 1: 1101 2: C:\work\foo.cab 3: 2 
MSI (s) (4C!74) [16:15:08:291]: Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035
```

`Note: 1: 1101 2: C:\work\Data2.cab 3: 2` indicates MSI error `1101 Could not open file stream: [2]` occured. This is extra error in the msi log, `Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035` still there.

Stepping in `CreateDataCab()` with debugger resulted in the following observations:

1. `Note: 1: 1101 2: C:\work\foo.cab 3: 2` error is added to the log right after failed `MsiRecordSetStream()` call when it returns error `161`.
2. `Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035` error is added to the log right after successful `MsiCloseHandle(hView)` call.
3. Dumping contents of `_Streams` table at the beginning of `CreateDataCab()` and at the end indicates that the new record is added to the table successfully.

This is what I have at the moment. Seems like the following happens:

1. `MsiRecordSetStream()` for the new record works fine. System can fetch file into the record if correct path is specified;
2. SQL request to insert new record to `_Streams` table succeeds;
3. `Data` field of newly added record contains no data.

I'm confused that MSI functions executed in custom action all pass but there is error in msi log file. Also changes to `_Streams` table are partially successful: new record added, but the record contains no data. Seems like it is potentially possible to update `_Streams` table at run-time, but something goes wrong with storing data in the table.

I have no issues with updating `_Streams` in msi files at build time. All works fine. But doing this at run-time from custom action is broken for me. Am I missing something in my CA function? Is it ever legal to alter `_Streams` at run-time?

**UPD**: I made some more investigation of the problem. I reworked my msi to call `CreateDataCab()` twice from two CA. Also modified `CreateDataCab()` itself. Pseudo code is following:

```
CreateDataCab() {
    dumpStream();

    openDb;
    _Streams["Data1.cab"].Data = "c:/work/Data1.cab";
    commitDb;
    closeDb;

    dumpStream();
}

dumpStream() {
    openDb;
    if ("Data1.cab" in _Streams) {
        save _Streams["Data1.cab"].Data to "c:/work/saved.cab";
    }
    closeDb;
}
```

When `CreateDataCab()` is called for the first CA the first `dumpStream()` outputs nothing, but the second on writes something to `c:/work/saved.cab`. This file appears binary equal to `c:/work/Data1.cab` which was used as a source for record stream. This indicates that stream data can be updated in `_Streams` table just fine. The data persists and remains in the db not to see that it was inserted and retrieved in two different `MsiGetActiveDatabase()/MsiDatabaseClose()` scopes. Very nice, however `Note: 1: 2263 2: Data2.cab 3: -2147287035` is still in the log.

When `CreateDataCab()` is called for the second CA things are not so nice. The first `dumpStream()` empties `c:/work/saved.cab` file. This means that `Data1.cab` record is still in `_Streams` table, but with empty stream data.

As it was noted that `_Streams` table is special I experimented with `Binary` table. Attempt to modify existing record resulted in `Note: 1: 2259 2:  3:  4:` error (Database: [2] Table(s) Update failed), i.e. `"UPDATE Binary SET Data = ? WHERE Name='Data1.cab'"` SQL query doesn't work. So I reworked CA code to use `MsiViewModify(hView, MSIMODIFY_INSERT_TEMPORARY, hRec)` and removed `Data1.cab` record from `Binary` table before running installation.

The first `CreateDataCab()` CA worked fine: insert OK, no errors in msi log, the second `dumpStream()` OK. However when `CreateDataCab()` was called for the second CA, the first `dumpStream()` dumped zero bytes and subsequent `MsiViewModify(hView, MSIMODIFY_INSERT_TEMPORARY, hRec)` failed.

Results for _Streams and Binary table are identical:

1. Inserted records persist across CA calls.
2. Stream data in added records doesn't persist across CA calls and set zero length in the second CA.

Inserting new temporary records in Binary table results in no error messages in msi log.
The good news is that it is possible to alter records with stream data from CA. Not so bad news is that in `Binary` table it is impossible to change data in existing records.
Bad news is that adding/changing stream data corrupts db.

I'll be very happy if somebody can challenge my conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

At run time, the database is read only. You have to use [INSERT ... TEMPORARY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021) instead of just INSERT, and I'm not certain whether it will work for the `_Streams` table. (I also generally have better luck with using the record-based API instead of the SQL-based API, i.e. open a view to the table, build a record, and then in this case [MsiViewModify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370519)(hView, MSIMODIFY_INSERT_TEMPORARY, hRec); but I don't think that's the problem here.)

That said, this use case sounds extremely unusual to me, so I'd be quite wary. Because the record is temporary, you will have to do this whenever the MSI is run - not just first time installation. Be sure to test all the scenarios you will want to support, including uninstall, repair, and any upgrade approaches. Especially if you may deliver minor upgrade patches.

Comment: Michael, I agree my use case is very unusual. I understand very well that all changes made to database from custom actions are temporary and will be lost when session terminates. I tried MsiViewModify(hView, MSIMODIFY_INSERT_TEMPORARY, hRec) instead of SQL, I tried MsiDatabaseCommit() - all the same, no luck, the same errors in msi log.

Comment: Yeah, _Streams is special, and apparently out of the scope of temporary edits. Perhaps all binary fields are as well. If so, can you get your desired results be editing the Media table to point to an external cab?

Comment: Yes, I can adjust Media record. But I don't like idea CA will create .cab file and leave it in the filesystem. Two reasons: #1: immediate actions should not alter the system state. #2 - need extra clean up in msi for this temporary .cab. Inserting .cab into running db looks more clean solution. So I have plan "B", but will fallback to it only if plan "A" is impossible. Right now I believe plan "A" is real, I'm just missing something.